# Using Thermal Conductivity measurements to estimate the thickness of a LI-900 Silica tile required to lower temperatures by 1450K

Tags: thermal-conduction

I'm diving into Fourier's Law at an IB Physics level, where we use the equation *ΔQ/Δt = k * A * ΔT/Δx*.

This equation is directly from the IB Databooklet, and as it's the first time it's been included in the curriculum, I'm hitting some snags. I'm using *Δx* to represent the thickness of a material. For a challenging question, I introduced my students to heat shielding, specifically LI-900 Silica Tiles, assuming a k value of 0.1 W/mK (sites show that it can be as low as about half of this, so I rounded up).

The problem posed was to determine the necessary thickness of these tiles to protect a shuttle experiencing an exterior temperature of 1500°C, but with an interior not exceeding 50°C. I've done the calculation myself, and I am not convinced I understand the answer I am getting so I'm trying to troubleshoot this issue. Could anyone here show me how you'd solve this, with your working and rearrangement? I'm also "rubber-ducking" this in the meantime to demonstrate the process to some students.

Secondly, this brings up the possibility that this question is impossible unless I know ΔQ/Δt - I was hoping it would be possible to answer this as a theoretical thickness regardless of the rate of transfer of heat based on the *k* value alone.

This is new in the IB curriculum and it has been 30 years since I have looked at problems like this and there are very few resources that I can find that target at this level of education.